# Encoding errors with shiny app and Russian

Tags: r, encoding, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I try to make shiny dashboard but have some encoding problems with the Russian language. Unfortunately, I need to use Russian because the database has column names in Russian and also clients of the dashboard can use only Russian UI. So, here is the pretty simple code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
load(url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_4850/datasets/movies.Rdata"))

# Define UI for application that plots features of movies 
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Sidebar layout with an input and output definitions 
  sidebarLayout(

    # Inputs
    sidebarPanel(

      # Select variable for y-axis
      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Y-axis:",
                  choices = c("imdb_rating", "imdb_num_votes", "critics_score", "audience_score", "runtime"), 
                  selected = "imdb_rating"),
      # Select variable for x-axis
      selectInput(inputId = "x", 
                  label = "X-axis:",
                  choices = c("imdb_rating", "imdb_num_votes", "critics_score", "audience_score", "runtime"), 
                  selected = "imdb_num_votes")
    ),

    # Outputs
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server function required to create the scatterplot
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Create scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = movies, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
      geom_point()
  })
}

# Create a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It works perfectly. But when I add a line with Russian text

```
print("Русский текст")
```

I recieve error:

```
Warning in checkEncoding(file) :
  The input file C:/path/test.R does not seem to be encoded in UTF8
Warning in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:/path/test.R'
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  C:/path/test.R:4:7: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
3: load(url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_4850/datasets/movies.Rdata"))
4: print("
         ^
Error in sourceUTF8(fullpath, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) : 
  Error sourcing C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpELJQpW\file36805da7570a
```

If I just delete the line

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Russian text works correctly, but of course, script doesn't work correctly - shiny app wasn't created.

Also if I add any comment in Russian

```
# Comment in russian: комментарий на русском
```

I see this error:

```
Warning in checkEncoding(file) :
  The input file C:/path/test.R does not seem to be encoded in UTF8
Warning in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:/path/test.R'
Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.
```

I tried to save the script in encoding format cp1251, but it didn't help.
Also I tried this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Russian_Russia")
```

I tried to save script in encoding format utf-8 and it helps for a while... But I opened script at the next day and it was broken again - all Russian symbols are replaced by strange things like "СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёР№ РєРѕРјРјРµРЅС‚" and errors mentioned above also returned.

Can someone give me an advice what to do with it?

Comment: `'СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёР№ РєРѕРјРјРµРЅС‚'.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')` returns `'русский коммент'` in Python… A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case… In terms of  `R` it could be something like `stri_encode('СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёР№ РєРѕРјРјРµРЅС‚',from="cp1251",to="UTF-8")`